# assigning godaddy domain to heroku nodejs app causes a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I have a godaddy domain name and I added it to my nodejs app hosted by heroku. However, when enter my new domain name in the browser I get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have added my domain name to the heroku app. This action then generates a DNS target say .herokudns.com.

I then configured my domains godaddy DNS management to have the CNAME WWW value to be .herokudns.com the DNS target provided by heroku.

I then configured the forwarding and set the values as follows.
FORWARD TO: http://.tech
FORWARD TYPE: Permanent (301)
SETTINGS: Forward only
Update my nameservers and DNS settings to support this change. => TRUE

This seems to be the way to get this done however I keep getting the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. Does anyone have a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the usual missing letter problem that occurs every once in a while.